# How to base64 string save as in (PDF , doc, xls , png.. ) in jquery , javascript , HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I m getting `base64 string` from server and I want to save file in my all browser(IE,FF , chrome).

suppose I am getting PDF base64 string then how to save in brwsore?

Similarly , Image ,doc base64 string  then how to save ?

Comment: Look at FileSaver.js

Comment: Any other suggestion  plz ..

Answer (score 1):

```
var myBaseString = charUri; // charURI is base64 encoded data of png image (data:image/png;base64,asP......)
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = myBaseString;
a.download = "chart.png";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Comment: While this can be the answer it's also good to explain it not just throwing some code.

Comment: Doesn't look related to the question.

Comment: I just create one anchor tag with "download" attribute and append to body tag than fire click event and remove the anchor tag.

For more Information please refer this link - http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_download.asp